# Responsive Navigation Transition not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I cannot get my ease-in transition to work on the navigation bar.

On Mobile when you click the burger, I would like a simple transition sliding in from right to left.

I tried using translateX (0%, 100%) instead of display (none, flex).

I feel like i am missing/forgetting something really simple.

What am I doing wrong / forgetting?

[Github Repo_branch](https://github.com/sofiaelsberg/toggle-project/tree/feature/adding-toggle-on-menu)

```js
// Js waits to run until after DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);


function ready() {
    console.log('DOM is ready');
    toggleMenu();
}

function toggleMenu() {
    console.log("script is imported and executed");

    //   Navigation opt4 - using eventlisteners and inline styling.... - works but very fucking ugly piece of code and unnecessary complicated

    const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const burgerToggle = document.querySelector('#burger');

    burgerToggle.addEventListener('click', show);

    function show() {
        burgerToggle.classList.toggle('toggle');
        navLinks.classList.toggle('nav-links_active')
    }

    function close() {
        navLinks.classList.toggle('nav-links_closed')
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1368px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Link styling */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
.navbar {
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Nav Links styling */
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


.nav-links a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}


@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .burger {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block!important;
    z-index: 11;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  button {
    border-color: black;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  }

  .nav-links a {
    color: black;
  }

  .nav-links {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links_closed {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-links_active {
    display: flex;
  }

  /* Toggle styling */

  .toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
    background-color: black;
  }

  .toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <p class="logo">LOGO</p>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <button>Sign In</button>
                <button>Sign Up</button>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, transition has no effect on changing display properties.
It's a good idea to use the transform parameter for example below:
Then a slide-down effect can be achieved.

Demo:

```js
// Js waits to run until after DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);


function ready() {
    console.log('DOM is ready');
    toggleMenu();
}

function toggleMenu() {
    console.log("script is imported and executed");

    //   Navigation opt4 - using eventlisteners and inline styling.... - works but very fucking ugly piece of code and unnecessary complicated

    const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const burgerToggle = document.querySelector('#burger');

    burgerToggle.addEventListener('click', show);

    function show() {
        burgerToggle.classList.toggle('toggle');
        navLinks.classList.toggle('nav-links_active')
    }

    function close() {
        navLinks.classList.toggle('nav-links_closed')
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1368px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Link styling */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
.navbar {
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Nav Links styling */
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


.nav-links a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}


@media (max-width: 3000px) {
  .burger {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block!important;
    z-index: 11;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  button {
    border-color: black;
    color: black;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  }

  .nav-links a {
    color: black;
  }

  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links_closed {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-links_active {
    display: flex;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  /* Toggle styling */

  .toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
    background-color: black;
  }

  .toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <p class="logo">LOGO</p>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <button>Sign In</button>
                <button>Sign Up</button>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```